# How can I add a small icon into a text box?

Tags: image

My team used to use Word for our meeting minutes. One of my team members has the unfortunate task of working on this one particular application. It's a multi-year project, so his "first priority" never changes. As a joke, one day someone put a little "lock" icon on his priority field. I'd like to replicate that now that we've transitioned to SharePoint.

I've tried to inject the raw html for placing a graphic, but it just puts the html as text on the page (which is a good thing, really - we wouldn't want potential hijacking or anything). I've also tried clicking the "edit page" button to find like an enable html button but was unable to find anything.

I don't really know much about sharepoint, so I don't know exactly how to describe my sharepoint environment. I know the field this goes into is not a rich text field, but a simple text field. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint is it? 2007, 2010, 2013. Are you referring to a field in a pagelayout like a title field or are you talking about fields in a form for list items?

Comment: I'm going go with list items. There's a list of people, and we each have a name, a first priority, and a second priority. As for version, I'm going to go with 2010 - there's a list elsewhere called "SharePoint 2010 Issues".